# Logout from facebook through an application using graph.facebook.com

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there any graph API available to logout a user from facebook? My application is able to succesfully retrieve user information and post on a user's wall. The problem is after authorization the facebook user is left in logged-in state and control goes back to my application. I want to logout the user after authprization is over and before the control comes back to my application. I want to use graph API and do it at the back end being implemented in Java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook PHP SDK uses a function like this:

```
public function getLogoutUrl($params=array()) {
  return $this->getUrl(
  'www',
  'logout.php',
  array_merge(array(
    'next' => $this->getCurrentUrl(),
    'access_token' => $this->getAccessToken(),
  ), $params)
  );
}
```

Which creates a URL like:
https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next={YOUR_ENCODED_URL}&access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}

I believe the encoded URL must be owned by the application to whom the access_token belong.
If you get that URL right, it'll work (just tried for one of my applications)

Comment: Thanks!  In ASP.NET with C#, I was able to use Response.Redirect() with this URL and it logged me out successfully. If Facebook ever mentions this URL in their documentation, it's not easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot log-out a user programatically via Java. You should create a logout link or button on the page instead.

Comment: Is it not possible to redirect to another web page in Java?  See Henrik Peinar's answer.

Comment: The question asked about logging out a user via API. I took that to mean a direct API call that results in a logout. Maybe I misunderstood the question XD

Comment: Ah, I do see what you mean.  Even though so much of it involves web pages, I sort of look upon the whole process as being a webservice that I can invoke URI's on.  I haven't been down the road yet of trying to invoke a logout when the client has no web browser.  That might be a whole different story.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code for logout from app

```
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
echo '<a href="'.$logoutUrl.'">Logout</a>';
```

replace above code in

```
try{
    //above code
 } catch {
    //other code
 }
```